# Calling functions from a double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

I created a pointer to a class I made that points to a dynamic array of pointers of this class. I am trying to use functions from the class I created (`Student`).

```
Student **list;

list[i] = TextToClass(tempCourse);
list[i].SetCourse(x);
list[i].SetGrades(inFile);
```

The assignment works. But using these functions does not work. How exactly do I go about using their functions?

Here is the error:

```
student.cpp: In member function ‘void Controller::ReadAndStore()’:
student.cpp:119: error: request for member ‘SetCourse’ in ‘((Controller*)this)->Controller::list[i]’, which is of non-class type ‘Student*’
student.cpp:121: error: request for member ‘SetGrades’ in ‘((Controller*)this)->Controller::list[i]’, which is of non-class type ‘Student*’
```

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete as well as concise.

Comment: When posting questions, always define "doe1s not work". Compile error? runtime error? If runtime eror: expected behavior? Actual behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
list[i]->SetCourse(x);
list[i]->SetGrades(inFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `list[i]`? Maybe if its a pointer, as you say, you should use `list[i]`**`->`**`SetCourse(x);`?

Don't feel shy posting some of your code instead of describing what you intended to do. If it would do what you intended you wouldn't be asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

As `Student **list` is a pointer to pointers, and then list[i] should be a pointer. So its methods should be called by notation "->", like above answer.